# first chern class versus compactifying divisor in Ramanujam's surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, kodaira-dimension

I have an elementary question about Ramanujam's surface. Ramanujam's surface is naturally the complement of a singular divisor $D$ in the one point blow up of $CP^2$, $\mathbb{F}_1$. One can resolve this to view Ramanujam's surface  as $X' \setminus D'$  for a certain normal crossings divisor $D'$. My question is: If we consider classes $A$ in $H_2(X')$ such that   $A \cdot D' > 0$, do we have that $$A \cdot D' > c_1(X')[A]$$

This is true when $X'$ is replaced by $\mathbb{F}_1$ and $D'$ is replaced by $D$, but I get a bit fuzzy on what happens when we resolve the divisor. As a remark, this question is undoubtedly low level, but I'm inexperienced with these sorts of computations so a bit of indulgence would be much appreciated.